# Mobile Cross-Platform Camera Frames Extraction

Tags: xamarin, react-native, mobile, cross-platform, flutter

Is there any cross-platform framework for mobile apps (Xamarin, Flutter, React-Native, etc.) that allows accessing frames from the camera's feed live?

In other words, is there any way to perform manipulations on live video (frame-by-frame) in cross-platform environments? (Similarly to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-camera-frames-extraction-d2c0f80ed05a) for iOS).

From what it seems, in Flutter for example, it's possible to display [a live preview of the camera](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera), but not to access the frames; and beside some [ghost-town questions](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112956/how-to-read-the-image-frames-from-a-camera-stream) I couldn't find much online about it.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin allows you to access and use each and every feature of all platforms.

The code will be platform specific but C#. I have one project in my repo where I'm using Xamarin.iOS to overlay [rectangle detection](https://github.com/Krumelur/RectangleDetection.iOS) onto the camera live feed. You can implement something similar using Xamarin.Android (using Android specific APIs).

You can then create an abstraction which will be consumed from a Xamarin.Forms app or you go with two separate C# based native apps.